# C# API for Z3 Installation

Tags: c#, z3

Could anyone please help me using C# Api in Z3. I have no idea what to do :-(

I wrote the followiing program in Visual C# 2010 Express :

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text; 
    using Microsoft.Z3;
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Config cfg = new Config()) {
                using (Context ctx = new Context(cfg)) {
                    Term x = ctx.MkConst("x", ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term y = ctx.MkConst("y", ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term zero = ctx.MkConst(0, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term one = ctx.MkConst(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term three = ctx.MkConst(3, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term fml = x > zero & ctx.MkEq(y, x + one) & y < three;
                    ctx.AssertCnstr(fml);
                    Model m = null;
                    LBool is_sat = ctx.CheckAndModel(out m);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(is_sat);

                    if (m != null)
                    {
                     m.Display(Console.Out);
                     m.Dispose();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

---

Following errors occured :

---

### The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are      you missing an assembly reference?)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Microsoft Z3 library in your C# projects follow these steps:

1. Go to http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/0a7db466-c2d7-4c51-8246-07e25900c7e7/
   and download + install the Z3 package.
2. Switch to Visual Studio. In the Solution Explorer window
   right click on the References tree node and select "Add Reference".
   In the "Add new reference" dialog navigate to the Microsoft.Z3.dll. You find the
   Microsoft.Z3.dll under `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin` on a
   Windows x64 bit machine or under `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin`
   on a Windows x86 machine. To use Parallel Z3 library choose the Microsoft.Z3.dll from the
   `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin_mt` or
   `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin_mt` directory.

A few notes regarding your code:

There is no method called `CheckAndModel()` on the `Context` class.
There is only a method called `CheckAndGetModel()`.
Furthermore there is no overload for the `MkConst()` of the form

```
ctx.MkConst(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
```

Instead use the following overload:

```
ctx.MkConst("1", ctx.MkIntSort());
```

Comment: Did that. The error is removed but a pop-up saying "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Z3.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." poped.

Comment: @user1291575: Under c:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin you will find a few more DLLs (z3.dll, msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll and vcomp100.dll). Copy those DLLs into your projects bin folder. Moreover make sure that your project is build as x86 assembly. Right click on your project in the solution explorer. Navigate to the build tab. Under platform target choose x86.

Comment: Hans: Thanks a lot. Your comments really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

```
ctx.MkConst("1", ctx.MkIntSort());
```

is not the numeral 1, but is an uninterpreted constant, whose name is "1".

If you want a numeral, then use:

```
ctx.MkNumeral(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
```